# how to go to a directory in gnome terminal which contains spaces as its name?

Tags: command-line, gnome, filemanager

I tried to `md5sum` a image but the path is long and contains spaces, and there is no option in the file manager to open that path in gnome-terminal. Like **right-click**-> **open current directory in terminal** like it used to be in other or previous Ubuntu.

How can I open a directory in terminal which has long path contains spaces and in Ubuntu?

Comment: I've edited you question to make it more meaningful. Is this what you wanted to say? Reply if still you've any doubt or you want some modification to the question :)

Comment: yes tha was exactly what i wanted to say... thanks anyway i have got my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a long path or go that path which contains the spaces follow this rule:

```
cd "the path of the directory"
```

or if you want to open in GUI way i,e in any file manager.

```
 nautilus "the path of the directory"
```

i,e start the path with a double quote (**"**) and keep pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. Pressing the tab key will automatically show the directory you want to open.

for example, to open your path in file manager or in terminal it self:

```
nautilus "/media/rajan/EXTRA/BACKUP/EXTRA/OS AND TOOLS/"
```

or

```
nautilus /media/rajan/EXTRA/BACKUP/EXTRA/"OS AND TOOLS"/
```

or if you want to just go to the path then this command:

```
cd /media/rajan/EXTRA/BACKUP/EXTRA/"OS AND TOOLS"/
```

Reply if still you are not clear.

Comment: the path is long and folder name contains spaces.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: rajan@rajan-OEM:~$ natilus /media/rajan/EXTRA/BACKUP/EXTRA/OS AND TOOLS/
No command 'natilus' found, did you mean:
 Command 'nautilus' from package 'nautilus' (main)
natilus: command not found

Comment: Follow the suggestion, it's `nautilus`, not `natilus` :)

Comment: @rajan: I've edited my answer.. Good that you've mentioned the path, now it will help to clear your doubt.. Also its **nautilus** the name of file manager; not **natilus** ;)

Comment: nothing happened..rajan@rajan-OEM:~$ nautilus /media/rajan/EXTRA/BACKUP/EXTRA/OS AND TOOLS/
rajan@rajan-OEM:~$ nautilus /media/rajan/EXTRA/BACKUP/EXTRA/OS AND TOOLS/
rajan@rajan-OEM:~$ nautilus /media/rajan/EXTRA/BACKUP/EXTRA/OS AND TOOLS/
rajan@rajan-OEM:~$

Comment: I think @rajan wants to open a terminal from `nautilus` and not the other way around

Comment: what is  nautilus??

Comment: @rajan `nautilus` is the file browser or manager in ubuntu.

Comment: @rajan: You have to start typing the path with a **double quote** like this: `nautilus "/media/rajan/EXTRA/BACKUP/EXTRA/OS AND TOOLS/"` or `nautilus /media/rajan/EXTRA/BACKUP/EXTRA/"OS AND TOOLS"/`

Comment: i want to open the directory inside terminal to do md5sum ,not opening in file manager